# ExtJS 4 building component from jsonp response

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Here is my situation. I have a JSONP feed that I want to render as an ExtJS component. I'm not sure the best way to go about this. There is the Ext.CompontentLoader feature, but is that applicable to this scenario? The alternative is to use an Ajax call to get it. However, I cannot figure out so far which API call makes JSONP possible. Ext.Ajax doesn't seem to support JSONP in ExtJS 4.

Answer (score 1):

First question I'm not too sure what are you going to achieve, but for the JsonP, you can probably check out [`Ext.data.JsonP`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP) class.